# Change the state of the buttons, activating one, deactivating the other and vice versa

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a blog where users can post their posts, other users registered on the platform can rate posts with a *like* or *dislike*. I have a problem with the fact that if the  *like* button is pressed, is can also press the *dislike* button, which cannot do, is can only press one button at a time, *like* or *dislike*, not both. How can I do?

I use Bootstrap framework to HTML/CSS Style

[Image what I would](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtNJk.png)

Javascript:

```
   <script>
      window.onload = bindEvents;

      function bindEvents() {
        btn_events();
      }

      function btn_events() {

        $('.btn_like').click(function(){
          var row_id = $(this).attr("data-id4");
          console.log ('Pressed button LIKE with id'+row_id);
          /*other code to increment value of post with value = value + 1*/
        });

        $('.btn_dislike').click(function(){
          var row_id = $(this).attr("data-id5");
          console.log ('Pressed button DISLIKE with id'+row_id);
          /*other code to increment value of post with value = value + 1*/
        });
      }
    </script>
```

PHP:

```
    echo '<div class="post"><p data-id0="'.$row["id_post"].'" >'.$user['nome']." ".$user['cognome']." <span class='time'>".time_since(time() - strtotime($row['datetime']))." ago </span> </p>";
    echo '<p data-id1="'.$row["id_post"].'">'.$row['comune']."</p>";
    echo '<p data-id2="'.$row["id_post"].'">'.$row['indirizzo']."</p>";
    echo '<p data-id3="'.$row["id_post"].'">'.$row['descrizione']."</p>";
    echo '<button type="button" name="view_details" class="btn btn-success btn-xs btn_like" data-id4="'.$row["id_post"].'">LIKE</button>';
    echo '&nbsp;';
    echo '<button type="button" name="view_details" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn_dislike" data-id5="'.$row["id_post"].'">DISLIKE</button>';
    echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Inside each of your click events, check if the other button is pressed.

Comment: How can I verify it using `$(this)` but with the other button's data-id?

Comment: try storing the state to a variable.  The variable should have the values of either 0, -1, or +1.  If it has one of the values while the opposite button is pressed... that's all the hints I'm giving.  Good luck.